# Запись видео в unity

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Интересует вопрос, как можно записать видео в unity? Наше в магазине capture video asset. Проблема в том, что он накладывает водяной знак на видео. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать это?

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов, даже, несколько:

- купить платную версию ассета [av-pro-movie-capture](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/2670) или опробовать [бесплатную обрезанную версию](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/97562)
- использовать бесплатный ассет, например [Video Capture](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/video-capture-75653) или [Unity Recorder](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/unity-recorder-94079) или их аналоги
- пользоватся внешними программами для записи видео с экрана, вроде Fraps, Camtasia Studio, Snag It, Movavi или подобных
- написать аналог платного ассета самому. В документации есть информация по захвату видео: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html